# windows registry read

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Using this code snippet:

```
TCHAR buf[255] = {0};
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
HKEY hKey = 0;
DWORD dwType = REG_DWORD;

if ( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Developer\\KGReader"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if( RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Developer\\KGReader\\ComPort"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        nrPort = _wtoi(buf);

    }

    if( RegQueryValueEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Developer\\KGReader\\KGID"), 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        nrCentrala = _wtoi(buf);
    }

}
```

1. No value is passed to `hKey` using `RegOpenKeyEx` method.
2. Although `RegOpenKeyEx` returns an ERROR_SUCCES, `RegQueryValueEx` returns 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). `KGID` and `ComPort` do exist,i added them myself, i double checked the paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the `hKey` obtained from the `RegOpenKeyEx()` call to the [`RegQueryValueEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions instead of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The second argument to `RegQueryValueEx()` is the name of the value, not a path.

For example:

```
if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,
                    TEXT("ComPort"),
                    0,
                    &dwType,
                    (LPBYTE)buf,
                    &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
```

Remember to reset `buf` and `dwBufSize` before the second call to `RegQueryValueEx`:

```
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
```

For error reporting purposes you should save the return value of the `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `RegQueryValueEx()` functions so the failure reason can be made known.

The posted code may be incomplete but ensure [`RegCloseKey(hKey)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724837%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called if the call to `RegOpenKeyEx()` was successful.

Comment: That is what i did at first, pass `hKey`, but as i stated, after `RegOpenKeyEx` it has no value assigned.

Comment: @MRM, I am unsure what has no value assigned?

Comment: My bad: in debug, after passing this line `if ( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Developer\\KGReader"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)` VS shows me that `hKey` is unused, but it has a value. Passing `hKey` and using only the name of the reg `ComPort`, not `\\ComPort`, i could read the values from the registry. Thank you!

Comment: one more thing: the registry `ComPort` has a DWORD value, let's say 20, that i want to pass to a int `nrPort`. But with my current code, `nrPort = _wtoi(buf);` `nrPort` takes only a `0` value.

Comment: @MRM, the nread it into a `DWORD`: `DWORD val; DWORD val_size = sizeof(DWORD);` and use `(LPBYTE) &val` as parameter that accepts the value.

Comment: @MRM, no need to use `_wtoi()`: it will already be a `DWORD` value. Just print it, it will be `20` (if `20` is in the registry).

Comment: or skip the _wtoi() and actually store it as a DWORD rather than a REG_SZ. Of course, validate you actually read a valid value, but if its supposed to be a DWORD numeric, you may want to just store it as such.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `RegQueryValueEx` should be the `HKEY` opened by `RegOpenKeyEx`. In addition, the second argument should just be a value name, not the full path:

```
if( RegQueryValueEx( hKey, TEXT("ComPort"), 0, &dwType,
                     (LPBYTE)buf, &dwBufSize ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
```